# Excel reference cell above

Tags: excel

I am trying to get a cell to equal 1 if a referenced cell equals 1, or to equal x+1 if the cell above it equals x, where x is in [0,15], otherwise, I'd like it to equal 0.

I am trying to combine `IF`/`OR` statements but I'm not sure how to combine them properly, and the command that is meant to locate the "cell above" --> `Address(Row(6)-1, Column(F))=1` is not working.

Comment: What is "referenced cell"? What is the relation between "a cell" and "a referenced cell"?

Comment: Screenshots? It's quite hard to understand what you want from this description/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood all requirements properly but I'd give this a try:

```
=IF($A$2=1;1;IF(AND(INDIRECT("R(-1)C"; FALSE) >= 0;INDIRECT("R(-1)C"; FALSE) <= 15);INDIRECT("R(-1)C"; FALSE)+1;0))
```

This formula will return
- 1 if cell $A$2 (the "referenced cell") contains 1
- x+1 if x is the value of the cell one row above the cell containing this formula, if it's value is between 0 and 15
- 0 in all other cases